# Elasticsearch match phrase prefix - confusion

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

```
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "product_code": {
                "query": "klock"
            }
        }
    }
```

Elasticsearch returns

```
{
 "_source": {
                    "id": 12,
                    "title": {
                        "de": "Katalog klockowy",
                        "en": "Katalog klockowy",
                        "pl": "Katalog klockowy"
                    }
             }
}
```

but not returns records like this

```
{
   "_source": {
                 "id": 52,
                  "title": {
                        "pl": "Klocki na sztuki"
                    }
                }
}
```

Why and how to fix it?

Field title.pl is the type of 'text'

Comment: is any analyzer used on field title.pl?

Comment: standard alayzer

Comment: I tried this out. It is working for me. Can you check your query and example , are they correct?